# Check if it's possible to build a triangle from three parameters (Cognitive Complexity to high)

Tags: javascript, loops, eslint

I can't find a way to code this challenge without either getting too complex or forging a on turn loop. The function receives three integers as parameters. Here follows my code.

```
function triangleCheck(lineA, lineB, lineC) {
  let ar12 = [lineA, lineB, lineC];
  if (triangleLineValidation(ar12) === 3 ) {
    return true;
  } else { return false}
}

function triangleLineValidation(ar12) {
let check = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < ar12.length; i += 1) {
    for (let j = i + 1; i < ar12.length; i += 1) {
      if (ar12[i] + ar12[j] > ar12[2 - i] && Math.abs(ar12[i] - ar12[j]) < ar12[2 - i]) {
        check += 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return check;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way to write this is:

```
const triangleLineValidation = (arr) => 
     (arr[0] + arr[1] > arr[2] && 
      arr[1] + arr[2] > arr[0] &&
      arr[2] + arr[0] > arr[1])
```

Comment: It's missing the "Math.abs(ar12[i] - ar12[j]) ..." part

Comment: @HugoMoutinho I don't think that's needed. In triangle, no side is bigger than sum of the other two sides. If this is satisfied, then we can have a triangle.

Comment: It's a requirement for the code to be accepted.

Comment: @Thomas I've tried this approach, but it also has Cognitive Complexity issues, since the code is being repeated many times, I guess...

Answer (score -1):

> `const triangleCheck = (a,b,c) => a+b>c && a+c>b && b+c>a && Math.abs(a-b)<c && Math.abs(a-c)<b && Math.abs(b-c)<a;`

> @Thomas I've tried this approach, but it also has Cognitive Complexity issues, since the code is being repeated many times, I guess

then let's break it down:

```
const checkSide = (a,b,c) => a + b > c && Math.abs(a - b) < c;
const triangleCheck = (a,b,c) => checkSide(a,b,c) && checkSide(b,c,a) && checkSide(c,a,b);
```

or

```
function triangleCheck(a, b, c) {
  return [a, b, c].every(triangleLineValidation);
}

function triangleLineValidation(c, i, array) {
  const a = array[(i + 1) % array.length];
  const b = array[(i + 2) % array.length];
  return a + b > c && Math.abs(a - b) < c;
}
```

never dealt with a computer having "Cognitive Complexity issues" with my code, so I'm not quite sure how to properly dumb it down.